# Optimizing radian to 2D Vector and vice-versa

Tags: math, vector

My current way of converting a radian to a 2D Vector is:

```
//Pseudo Code
vector2D(cos(radian),sin(radian)); //x, y
```

and vice-versa is:

```
//Pseudo Code
radian = atan2(vector2D.y,vector2D.x);
```

However doing so seems to be very unoptimized, especially doing so 3,000 times per frame, at 60 FPS.

What are some optimized alternative ways of converting them?

I've tried to Google it, but to no avail, I decided to ask the community.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Why exactly do you think this is a problem?

Comment: The problem is that you are allocating `Vector2` objects 3000 times a seconds. Why not keep one object, and just change its fields.

Comment: 3000 trig functions is not that much work. Profile and look for bottlenecks before optimizing.

Comment: @ja72 how do you know the way OP is allocating stuff?  Maybe they have  a `vector2D[3000]` and need to do some work in polar coordinates, then convert back.

Comment: Unless you specify how these values are used, it is impossible to optimize your code. Are there results that can be pre-computed, or cached? Are there any repetitions/re-evaluations of the same code? Maybe you don't need the radian value and just keep the x & y components. Like subsitute `COS(φ) = x/SQRT(x^2+y^2)` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that this trig code is a bottleneck your program.  I ran the following test program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    int const N = 3000;
    int const FRAMES = 10000;

    float xs[N], ys[N];

    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<Clock> Time;

    Time start = Clock::now();

    for (int frame = 0; frame < FRAMES; ++frame)
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        float theta = atan2(ys[i], xs[i]);
        theta += 0.01;
        xs[i] = cos(theta);
        ys[i] = sin(theta);
    }

    Time end = Clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> seconds = end - start;
    double fps = FRAMES / seconds.count();
    std::cout << fps << " fps\n";
}
```

Compiled with MSVC 2013, 32-bit release mode on an Intel i7-4770:

```
3620.56 fps
```

*edit*: put another way, the trig code would take 1.6% of your CPU time per frame at 60 FPS.  This is not a lot, but it's not nothing either.